# How to call vue instance outside it in Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I call the test vue in javascript? Here is my code, I want to call test when I do something in javascript function.

```
function clickit() {
   this.test.fetchTestData();    
}

var test = new Vue({
    el: '#viewport',
    data: {
        test_data: []
    },

    mounted: function () {
        this.fetchTestData();
    },

    methods: {
        fetchTestData: function () {
            $.get(test.json, function (data) {
                this.test_data = data;
               alert(this.test_data.isActive);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a Vue JS component method from outside the component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33682651/call-a-vue-js-component-method-from-outside-the-component)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are attempting to use `this` inside `clickit()` where `this` refers to `window`, so you just need to remove `this` and it should call the method inside the view model:

```
function clickit() {
   test.fetchTestData();    
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you compile this code with 'vue-cli-service build' the variable 'test' will not be defined, but you can make it visible to javascript in the mounted function:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#viewport',
    data: {
        test_data: []
    },

    mounted: function () {
        window.test=this;
    },

    methods: {
        fetchTestData: function () {
            $.get(test.json, function (data) {
                this.test_data = data;
               alert(this.test_data.isActive);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Then you can call it from javascript:

```
function clickit() {
   window.test.fetchTestData();    
}
```

Comment: Works for me, VueJS 2.3.3 version.  Thanks.

Comment: talk about polluting the global namespace. at least create a namespace for your stuff e.g. ```window.myNameSpace.test```

Answer (score 7):

**Another way to call VueJs method using external java-script.**

Firstly we should create a file. name event.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';

export default new Vue({
    data: {

    }
});
```

After that we should import that event.js to our component

```
import Event from "../event.js";
```

Then we can emit an event on our javascript function like below

```
function yourJavascriptFunction(){
    Event.$emit("fetchdata");
}
```

In your component, mounted property should be like below:

```
mounted() {
  Event.$on("fetchdata", group => {
    this.fetchData();
 });
},
methods() {
  async fetchData() {
     console.log('hoooray :)');
  }
},
```