# How can I call method in other component on vue.js 2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

My first component like this :

```
<template>
    ...
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        ...
        methods: {
            addPhoto() {
                const data = { id_product: this.idProduct}
                const item = this.idImage
                this.$store.dispatch('addImage', data)
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.createImage(item, response)
                    });
            },
        } 
    }
</script>
```

If the method addPhoto called, it will call ajax and then it will get response ajax

I want to send response ajax and another parameter to method createImage. Method createImage is located in other component (second component)

My second component like this :

```
<template>
    <div>
        <ul class="list-inline list-photo">
            <li v-for="item in items">
                <div v-if="clicked[item]">
                    <img :src="image[item]" alt="">
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="thumb-check"><span class="fa fa-check-circle"></span></a>
                </div>
                <a v-else href="javascript:;" class="thumb thumb-upload"
                   title="Add Photo">
                    <span class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        ...
        data() {
            return {
                items: [1,2,3,4,5],
                clicked: [], // using an array because your items are numeric
            }
        },
        methods: {
            createImage(item, response) {
                this.$set(this.clicked, item, true)
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

How can I run the createImage method on the second component and after that it can change the element in the second component?

Comment: Is this possible? If not whether there is another solution to change the element in the second component when the addPhoto method is executed?

Comment: What is the relationship between the first component and the second? Are they parent-child or siblings? Typically you would [`$emit`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit) an event from the child and register a handler for that event in the parent, otherwise you can get a reference to a component using [`ref`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) and use that to call the method directly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If these 2 components are siblings (no parent & child), then one solution is to use event bus.

General idea is to build a global event handler like so:
in `main.js`

`window.Event = new Vue();`

Then in your first component fire an event:

```
....
.then((response) => {
     Event.$emit('createImage', item, response)
});
```

and in second component register a handler for listening to `createImage` event in `mounted()` hook:

```
...
mounted() {
    Event.$on('createImage', (item, response) => {
        // your code goes here
    }
}
```

You can find more info by reading [this turtorial](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/) and watching [this screen cast](https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/13).

Comment: tutorial link is not found, please update if you could.

Answer (score 15):

No two components don't have a parent/child relation. They are all connected through the root vue instance. To access the root vue instance just call `this.$root` and you get the root instance.

```
....
.then((response) => {
    this.$root.$emit('createImage', item, response)
});
```

and in the second component make the function that needs to be triggered

```
...
mounted() {
    this.$root.$on('createImage', (item, response) => {
        // your code goes here
    })
}
```

It acts more like a socket. The event will be globally available, due to `$root`.

***N.B.** adding the vue instance to global window object is a bad practice*