# How to access a vue component method from another app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have this code that works fine in pure html/javascript, but not in vuejs. I have this function named myMethod().
When debugging in the javascript console,I can access it like this: myMethod("toto"). But in vuejs it is only accessible like this: $vm0.myMethod("toto").

I absolutely need it to be accessible like this: myMethod("toto").

Is that even possible in vue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `window.myMethod = () => {}` and use it anywhere

Comment: To put it in context, my vue app is just a browser tab in a cellphone app. This cellphone app checks the vue app code for a method named myMethod() and calls it when needed. This app can't call window.myMethod() because it just can't!

Answer (score 0):

For non-parent-child relation, then this is the same as this one. Call one method, apparently any method of a component from any other component. Just add a `$on` function to the `$root` instance and call form any other component accessing the `$root` and calling `$emit` function.

On First component

```
    ....
    mounted() {
        this.$root.$on('component1', () => {
            // your code goes here
            this.c1method()
        }
    }
```

and in the second component call the `$emit` function in `$root`

```
    ...
    c2method: function(){
     this.$root.$emit('component1') //like this
    },
```

It acts more like a socket. Reference here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50343039/6090215

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I think this is working within one vue app, or am I missing something? My vue component method is to be called by another app which is not a vuejs app. Not another component from my vue app. I hope I am being clear...