# vue.js - call component method from another component

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I want to use the getProjects() method of Component 2 to refresh my table after adding a data. Both of these components are attached in a blade.php

Component 1.vue

```
 methods: {
  addData() {
    this.attemptSubmit = true;
    this.validate = true;
    this.errors = [];
    if (this.errors) event.preventDefault();
    axios
    .post('/api/department', {
                department: this.department,
                section: this.section
    })
    .then(response => {
      this.validate = false;
      this.department = '';
      this.section = '';
      this.errors = '';
      this.output = response.data;
      //--- I want to insert the getProjects() method here 
    })
    .catch(error => this.errors = error.response.data.errors)
  },
```

Component 2.vue

```
methods: {
    getProjects(url = '/api/departments') {
      this.tableData.draw++;
      axios
      .get(url, {params: this.tableData})
      .then(response => {
        let data = response.data;
        if (this.tableData.draw == data.draw) {
          this.projects = data.data.data;
          this.configPagination(data.data);
        }
      })
      .catch(errors => {
        console.log(errors);
      });
    },
```

Comment: It's good to create separate service for get project, and you can call it from both component.

Comment: Do you mean that I should separate it in another component? I'll be having a lot of different forms with each forms having its own data table component.

Comment: You look like needing a `mixin`

Comment: I checked about mixin. The way I see it, I need to create different mixin for different forms since each forms have different axio.get URL.

Comment: you can pass that url as parameters ....

Comment: I was able to do it now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes it is possible. Step 3 will do what you explicitly asked but there are better ways.

**Three ways.**

1) **VUEX:** Move the method you wish to call, to Vuex and any associated reactive data properties to the store. And use getters to retrieve the updated data.

2) **MIXINS:** With mixins you would move your component2.vue and associated data properties to a mixin, and import it in both components, allowing it to be called from each.

3) **Hacky fix** that actually calls the method from another component (not best practice)

You can mount methods to $root and call them from another component, by emiting a event. Using your example it would look like the following.

Components2.vue // mount the method you wish to call

```
// new code
  mounted() {

    this.$root.$on("getProjects", () => {

      return this.getProjects(url = '/api/departments');
    });
  }
```

Component1.vue // call the mounted method

```
 methods: {
   // new code
    emitGetProjects() {
     this.$root.$emit("getProjects") //like this
    }
  },
```

more info here [How can I call method in other component on vue.js 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45097278/how-can-i-call-method-in-other-component-on-vue-js-2/50343039#50343039) in case i made any typos

Answer (score 4):

You should use vuex. See https://medium.com/js-dojo/vuex-2638ba4b1d76

You call the vuex action from your component and in this action, you can make the axios call directly or use another service to make your api calls.

Mutations should never be called from components only from actions inside the store.

kind regards

Comment: I'll try to study this one since I'm fairly new with vue.js Thank you very much!

Comment: Feel free to ask if you need further information or some help.