# Vue3 - How call function from another component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I start working with Vue3 and created some basic app with adding items to list.

I have two componetnts: **ItemList** and **ItemForm**. Both are added to main **App.vue** component like that:

**App.vue - simplified**

```html
<template>
  <ItemsList/>
  <ItemForm/>
</template>
```

In **ItemsList** I have prop called 'items'. And function addItem() for adding new items to list.

In **ItemForm** have form and on submit I want send this data from form to **ItemsList** component to update list view.

I checked few things and nothing works for me (I read that in Vue2 was EventBus which was used for such a situation). I don't wanna also learn some bad way to solve that problems so I ask you for help.

#EDIT

**App.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <ItemsList/>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <ItemForm/>
  </div>
</template>
    
<script setup>
import ItemForm from "@/components/ItemForm";
import ItemsList from "@/components/ItemsList";
</script>
```

**ItemForm.vue**

```html
<template>
  <form v-on:submit="addItem">
    <input type="text" v-model="title"/>
    <textarea v-model="description"></textarea>
    <button>Add item</button>
  </form>
</template>
    
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      title: '',
      description: '' 
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addItem(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**ItemsList.vue**

```html
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in items">
      <p><b>{{ item.title }}</b></p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
    
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addItem: function(item) {
      this.items.push(item);
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: why are u mixing composition api and options api? just wondering

Comment: I started learn so that just beginner mistake, canyou explain me what I doing wrong?

Comment: honestly idk if that is a mistake, cuz idk if its ok to use both apis or if u should stick to one of them. i'd say maybe u should stick to one of them

Comment: now I notice that I mixed this two approaches :) do you have solution for my problem ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue.js - How to call method from another component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42990308/vue-js-how-to-call-method-from-another-component)

Comment: This solution is for older version of Vue.

Comment: @Zaki This solution has answers to new Vue 3 version to.

Comment: I will try that on Monday and let you know

Comment: @Zaki Oh and Vue.js way of programming works same in Vue 3.

Comment: @Mises there is no longer $on function in Vue3 - https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/events-api.html#_2-x-syntax

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I found solution for my problem: https://pinia.vuejs.org/

Maybe someone will need this info.

### Edit

You can use store to manage data across your application

Comment: Nope, it won't help anyone. Pinia is a state management library, not a function caller of components.

Comment: Yes, but I can use it as a items store

Comment: Because in Vue3 there is no longer $on function and global events are not recomended using stores are solution for sharing data across app

Answer (score 1):

You probably should use [emits](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html) to share the data from the child component to the parent. I have set up a Vue3 Composition API example. Check it out [here](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNqlUstuwjAQ/JWVLwkSSe4IEBXtod9QVyIkSxuIH7I3aSvEv3c3hIKo1Etv9sxkdryTo3rwPu87VDM1JzS+LQmX2s7XznhYRbR1VpdULrSqyrbdltVBKyhYwZrG+o6gz4yrsWWF+XoWZBTMixs/vsYqNJ4gInWekcZ4FwiOEHAHJ9gFZyDhIMkPNUQ443khF8nJtLaVs5FgHAcLsUiTZHKlLlmZk/SwWF7UeV+2HY64hDzHWqqpOo/NTOnzfXSWN3LUFkCPRNRqBgMiGEeRu1bvRD7OiiLuKsm3j7kLbwWf8tBZagzmGE22De4jYmBjraY3HgWDPYYs8KIxYPjL8076y1dsT9qe+CmXbd23uu2IHG8JYFW1TXXg0rZk13LEOp2cPfqM8JOY2gwEkOPSbD1sbCOS/7XLLx9bQtNQlCpw11h8klv6ksisRx6VvN4Uek3J+nQihQ5fp1f5FJLoDA4x5V+4Vnv6Bu+kAYw=):

Parent:

```html
<template>
<Comp @send-data="callback" />

<input v-model="myInput" />
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import Comp from './Comp.vue'

const myInput = ref('')

const callback = data => myInput.value = data
</script>
```

Child:

```html
<template>
<button
  @click="btnClicked()"
  v-text="`Click to send data`"
/>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
  
const emits = defineEmits(['sendData'])

const btnClicked = () => emits('sendData', 'some data')
</script>
```

* If you share some code, we can help you better and write better examples that get near what you want to achieve too.

Comment: I guess OP wants some `defineExpose` too, but it's not clear yet for sure.

Comment: @ericmp I added more code to post. I see that you show how share data when we have parent - child relation in my example I think that this wouldn't work right?