# Rerender component data from another component. Vue 3.2

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to refresh component data from another component. When a user clicks **'Save Changes'** I send post, insert data into db in laravel from `CreateNewAccessGroupModal` template. Then, after response success I need to refresh component (`AccessGroup` template) and show updated row in view (access_groups arr). What I need to do to achieve it? I can not understand how to use `defineEmits` properly.

**Main template:**

```html
<template>
  <MainLayout title="Access Groups" :sidebar="true">
    <main class="main main-p">
      <div class="main-content">
        <div class="main-head">
          <ul class="breadcrumbs">
            <li class="breadcrumbs-item">
              <a href="#" class="breadcrumbs-link">
                <i class="ico-home"></i>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="breadcrumbs-item">
              <a href="#" class="breadcrumbs-link">Settings</a>
            </li>
            <li class="breadcrumbs-item">
              <a href="#" class="breadcrumbs-link">Assets groups</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <h1 class="main-head__title">Access Groups</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="main-actions">
          <div class="main-actions__wrap">
            <div class="main-actions__btns">
              <a
                href="#modalCreateAccessNewGroup"
                class="btn btn-bordered"
                data-toggle="modal"
              >
                <i class="ico-plus"></i>
                Create group
              </a>
              <button class="btn btn-light">
                Delete
                <i class="ico-delete"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="main-body">
          <div class="table">
            <div class="table-head">
              <div class="table-head__wrap">
                <div class="table-head__item table-head__item-checkbox">
                  <div class="checkbox">
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      class="checkbox-input"
                      id="checkboxGroupNameAll"
                    />

                    <label
                      for="checkboxGroupNameAll"
                      class="checkbox-label"
                    ></label>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="table-head__item">Group name</div>

                <div class="table-head__item table-head__item-btn"></div>

                <div class="table-head__item table-head__item-btn"></div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="table-body">
              <div class="table-body__wrap">
                <AccessGroup :access_groups="access_groups" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </MainLayout>

  <CreateNewAccessGroupModal :permissions_param="permissions_param" />
</template>
```

**CreateNewAccessGroupModal template:**

```html
<template>
  <div
    class="modal fade"
    id="modalCreateAccessNewGroup"
    tabindex="-1"
    role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="modalCreateNewGroup"
    aria-hidden="true"
    data-backdrop="static"
  >
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h3 class="modal-title">Create new group</h3>

          <button
            type="button"
            class="close"
            data-dismiss="modal"
            aria-label="Close"
          >
            <i class="ico-close"></i>
          </button>
        </div>

        <form @submit.prevent="createNewAccessGroup">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="modal-box">
              <div class="modal-hold">
                <div class="input">
                  <label class="input-label">Group name:</label>

                  <div class="input-box">
                    <input
                      v-model="group_name"
                      type="text"
                      class="input-field"
                    />

                    <span class="invalid-feedback">Required field</span>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="input">
                  <label class="input-label">Description:</label>

                  <div class="input-box">
                    <input
                      v-model="description"
                      type="text"
                      class="input-field"
                    />

                    <span class="invalid-feedback">Required field</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="attribute">
                <div class="attribute-head">Permissions</div>

                <div
                  v-for="(permission, index) in permissions_param"
                  :key="index"
                  class="attribute-body"
                >
                  <div class="attribute-row">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                      <input
                        v-model="permissions"
                        :value="index"
                        type="checkbox"
                        class="checkbox-input"
                        :id="index"
                      />

                      <label :for="index" class="checkbox-label"></label>
                    </div>

                    {{ permission.label }}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer modal-footer__end">
            <div class="modal-text">
              By clicking save button API key for the group will be generated
            </div>

            <button id="close" class="btn btn-m-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">
              Cancel
            </button>

            <button class="btn btn-m-primary">Save Changes</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from "vue";
  import { useForm } from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3";

  let props = defineProps({
    permissions_param: Array,
  });

  const emit = defineEmits(["update-permissions"]);

  let group_name = ref("");
  let description = ref("");
  let permissions = ref([]);

  function createNewAccessGroup() {
    axios
      .post("/access-group/create-new", {
        group_name: group_name.value,
        description: description.value,
        permissions: permissions.value,
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        if (response.data.success) {
          emit("update-permissions", response.data.success);
        } else {
          //show warning
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {});
  }
</script>
```

**AccessGroup template:**

```html
<template>
  <div
    v-for="(access_group, index) in access_groups"
    :key="index"
    class="table-row"
  >
    <div class="table-row__item table-row__item-checkbox">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input" id="checkboxGroupName1" />
        <label for="checkboxGroupName1" class="checkbox-label"></label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="table-row__item">
      <span class="table-row__item-box">{{access_group.group_name}}</span>
    </div>

    <div class="table-row__item table-row__item-btn">
      <a href="#modalViewUsers" class="btn btn-m-secondary" data-toggle="modal"
        >Users</a
      >
    </div>

    <div class="table-row__item table-row__item-btn">
      <a
        href="#modalEditAccessGroup"
        class="btn btn-m-secondary"
        data-toggle="modal"
      >
        Details
        <i class="ico-edit"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <EditAccessGroupModal />

  <ViewAccessGroupUsersModal />
</template>
```

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74317057/14569750) you have an example on how to share data from a child component to its parent

Comment: ericmp,thanks for answer. Could you show small example with my data please. I do not understand exactly example.

Comment: emit won't work, because these components are siblings, not parent-child

Answer (score 0):

**Vue is reactive by default.**
**In case you use state manager (Vuex/Pinia)** - inside the CreateNewAccessGroupModal just put response's result to your store.
In the AccessGroup you can get a reference to that value in the store.
Once you update store with new value inside the CreateNewAccessGroupModal, the AccessGroup should receive new value. Why? **Because Vue.js is reactive by default**. Some API of Vuex that should help you - https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html , https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html , https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api.html . Pinia has similar solutions.

**In case you do not use state manager** - it depends on the organisation of your components and business requirements).
If I were you, I would used provide/inject of Vue3 - https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html .
Your Main template is a parent for both components, so only Main template is able to "speak" with both components. Inside Main I would define 1) ref object to put result of response in and 2) the method to do it, for example

```
// Main.vue
<script>
import { ref, provide } from 'vue'
const resultOfResponse = ref(null)
const putResultInside = (result) => {
  resultOfResponse.value = result;
}
// PROVIDE IT FOR YOUR descendants (AccessGroup, CreateNewAccessGroupModal etc) !
provide('MainProvide', {
  resultOfResponse,
  putResultInside,
})
```

and I would use it inside components:

```
// CreateNewAccessGroupModal.vue
<script>
import { inject } from 'vue'
//...
const {putResultInside} = inject('MainProvide')
const makeRequest = () => {
//...
  putResultInside(reponse.data.your.result)
}

// AccessGroup.vue
<script>
import { inject } from 'vue'
// use it as you wish :)
const {resultOfResponse} = inject('MainProvide')
```

Sometimes provide/inject are not explicit enough, in this case you can use provide/inject only for CreateNewAccessGroupModal.vue, but pass resultOfResponse from Main to AccessGroup via props. As you wish)
**Why won't *emit* work? Emit will work only if you have "conversation" between parent-child components.

As I can see, your components are siblings, they cannot "catch" emits of each other.**