# Call a method of another component

Tags: vuejs2

How to call a method of another component ?

Like I have a component named `Modal.vue` . I have a method like below

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'modal'
        methods: {
            getUsers() {
                //some code here
            }
        },
        created: function () {
            this.getUsers();
        }
    }
</script>
```

I would like to call that method in another component named `Dashboard.vue`.

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'dashboard'
        methods: {
            add_adddress () { 
                this.getUsers();  // I would like to access here like this
                //some code here
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33682651/call-a-vue-js-component-method-from-outside-the-component) question, but how can I use `$emit`,`$on`,`$broadcast` in my current setup ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a Vue JS component method from outside the component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33682651/call-a-vue-js-component-method-from-outside-the-component)

Comment: In order to use the `emit` the components need to be called from each other for e.g. dashboard component uses the modal component, and then you emit from the modal to the dahsboard.  If the components are separate I would suggest that you create a mixin which you can import in any component and have all its methods available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use `emit` one of the components need to call the other (parent and child). Then you `emit` from the child component to the parent component. For example if Dashboard component uses the Modal component you can `emit` from the Modal to the Dashboad.

If your components are separate from one another you can make use of Mixins.  You can create a mixin `UsersMixin.js` like the following:

```
export default {
    methods: {
        getUsers: function () {
            // Put your code here for a common method
        }
    }
}
```

Then import the mixin in both your components, and you will be able to use its methods:

`Modal.vue`

```
<script>
import UsersMixin from './UsersMixin';
export default {
    name: 'modal'
    mixins: [
        UsersMixin
    ],
    created: function () {
        this.getUsers();
    }
}
</script>
```

`Dashboard.vue`

```
<script>
import UsersMixin from './UsersMixin';
export default {
    name: 'dashboard',
    mixins: [
        UsersMixin
    ],
    methods: {
        add_adddress () { 
            this.getUsers();  // I would like to access here like this
            //some code here
        }
    },
}
</script>
```