# Create component on the fly with custom data

Tags: vue.js, timeout, axios, interceptor, mount

First of all, I’m not a vue expert, so i’m sorry if i missunderstand anything

In my app I need to implement the following:
Every request that has a timeout should show a popup where the user would be able to resend the request. For this, I’m using axios, and I have created an interceptor for catch the timeout request

```
export const authenticated = Axios.create({
  timeout: 100,
})

authenticated.interceptors.response.use(
  response => {
    return response
  },
  error => {
    if (error.code === 'ECONNABORTED') {
      //create and show popup
      var ComponentClass = Vue.extend(TimeoutModalDialog)
      var instance = new ComponentClass()
      instance.$mount('#page')
    }
    return Promise.reject(error)
  }
)
```

Here I have all the data of the request in ‘error.config’ so what I want is to send this object to the new component (TimeoutModalDialog).
I would like to know also if there is a better way to create and show dynamic vue components.

I hope you can help me
Best regards

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37521683/4617687

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I have implemented this to solve my problem:

```
authenticated.interceptors.response.use(
  response => {
    return response
  },
  error => {
    if (error.code === 'ECONNABORTED') {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var modalDialogId = "timeout-modal-dialog";
        if($('#' + modalDialogId).length){
          instance.$children[0].loadingComplete = true;
        } else {
          var ComponentClass = Vue.extend(TimeoutModalDialog);
          instance = new ComponentClass({
            propsData: {
              retryFunction: function () {
                instance.$children[0].loadingComplete = false;
                authenticated.request(error.config).then((response) => {
                  instance.$children[0].loadingComplete = true;
                  $("#" + modalDialogId).modal("close");
                  resolve(response);
                }, (error) => {
                  instance.$children[0].loadingComplete = true;
                  reject(error);
                })
              },
              cancelFunction: function () {
                instance.$children[0].loadingComplete = true;
                $("#" + modalDialogId).modal("close");
                reject(error);
              },
              dialogId: modalDialogId
            }
          });
          instance.$mount();
          document.getElementById('modalVueGeneric').appendChild(instance.$el);
        }
      });
    } else {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  }
);
```

And it solves my problem.

Thanks Laran for your suggestion.