# How do I call a Vue method into a plain javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

Vue app code:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#APP",
    data: {some data},
    methods: {
            some_method: function() {
                   ......
            }
});

some_js_func = function() {
       "How do I call 'some_method' to here"
};
some_js_func();
```

I tried by calling `app.some_method()`, but it's  not working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33682651/call-a-vue-js-component-method-from-outside-the-component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With pure JavaScript, you can access the `some_method` function via the `$options` property like this:

```js
var app = new Vue({
    methods: {
            some_method: function() {
                   alert("hello");
            }}
});

someJSfunc = function() {
       app.$options.methods.some_method();
};

someJSfunc();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: why dont call the method directly: `app.some_method();` ?

Comment: @Imarqs, this this not possible in Vue2 I guess.

Comment: Worked for me like this `window.someJSfunc = function() {
       app.$options.methods.some_method();
};`

Comment: with the app object, you can call app.some_method(); directly.