# How to trigger a method in Single File Component from another Single File Component VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

**I have Three components I want to trigger the `show()` method that is located in `overlay.vue` component, from the `about.vue` component**

*I am a beginner so I wish if I found some help from you guys*

**first is `overlay.vue`**

```
<template>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "overlay",
    methods: {
        show() {
            document.querySelector(".overlay").style.display = "block";
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

**second is `about.vue`**

```
<template>
    <section class="about">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row video">
                <div class="col-lg-6 order-lg-1 order-2">
                    <img
                        class="dots img-fluid"
                        src="../assets/images/dots.svg"
                        alt="dots"
                    />
                    <div class="video-wrapper">
                        <div class="video-img">
                            <img
                                class="img-fluid"
                                src="../assets/images/video.png"
                                alt="#"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div class="video-i">

                            <!-- ***************************************************************
                            ***** this is where i want to trigger the method using this below a tag*****
                            *************************************************** -->
                            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></a>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>
```

**The third which is the parent `app.vue` where I import `about.vue` and `overlay.vue`**

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <overlay></overlay>
        <about></about>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import overlay from "./components/overlay";
import about from "./components/about";
export default {
    name: "App",
    components: {
        about,
        overlay
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Use the store.  In the `show` method, set a store value to true.  Then in about.vue, have bind the show state to the div you want to modify.  
If you're doing don manipulations (`querySelector`) in a vue app, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: I still cant do it. :((((((((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**because the two components are siblings and not imported in each other I coulden't use $ref and the best choice is to use `Store`**

*this is my store code*

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        showOverlay: false
    },
    mutations: {
        //showing the overlay
        TOGGLE_OVERLAY(state, payload) {
            state.showOverlay = payload;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        //showing the overlay
        toggleOverlay(context, payload) {
            context.commit("TOGGLE_OVERLAY", payload);
        }
    },
    getters: {
        getStatus: state => state.showOverlay
    }
});
```

**and here where i dispatch it. I dispatch it from `about.vue` or any other component as well**

`<a @click.prevent="toggleOverlay" href="#"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></a>`

```
    methods: {
        toggleOverlay() {
            this.$store.state.showOverlay = !this.$store.state.showOverlay;
            this.$store.dispatch(
                "toggleOverlay",
                this.$store.state.showOverlay
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, in your `app.vue` set a variable to show your `overlay.vue` or not. And then in the `overlay.vue` set a `props` that change the style of your component. This solution is not using a dom manipulation.

1. `app.vue`

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <overlay :show="show_overlay"></overlay>
        <about></about>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import overlay from "./components/overlay";
import about from "./components/about";
export default {
    name: "App",
    data(){
        return {
            show_overlay:false
        }
    },
    components: {
        about,
        overlay
    }
};
</script>
```

2. `overlay.vue`

```
<template>
    <div class="overlay" :style="[(this.show) ? 'display:block' : 'display:none']"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "overlay",
    props:{
        show:{
            default:false,
            type:Boolean
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: You can add buttons or text or something, and when it clicked, just simply change the show variable into true. example `<button @click="show=true;">Show overlay</button>`

Comment: I am really grateful for this, but this is not exactly what i want.
I want to do this function from a sibling component which is `about.vue` by clicking at button or whatever, not from the parent which is `app.vue`.
But thank you so much for this respond too.

Comment: Oh I just understand what your question means

Comment: Okay, Sir. I really still don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: 1. You can add `ref` to your `overlay.vue`
2. in your `about.vue` in your href you can call the show function at `overview.vue` by using `$parent.$children.$refs.[ref_name].show()`

Here a useful example from other user : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33682651/call-a-vue-js-component-method-from-outside-the-component