# Calling Vue3 component methods from outside

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, integration

My Vue 3 application is as follow:

app.js

```js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./app.vue";

let vm = createApp(App)
vm.mount("#app");

window.vm = vm
```

app.vue

```html
<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  methods: {
    async someMethod() {
      this.data.push(1);
    }
    //...

}
</script>
```

---

In Vue 2, [it is possible to reach internal methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33682651/89769) using the following code:

```js
vm.$children[0].someMethod()
```

However, it does not work with Vue3.

How can I integrate my Vue component to an external API using a **similar technique in Vue 3**?

Comment: It's a bad practice to access internals through $children. If you need to affect the app from the outside, it should expose public method that interacts with children. In your case no children are involved, `vm` is App comp instance and it should be vm.someMethod().There's at least one mistake, createApp returns app instance and not comp instance. It should be `vm = app.mount("#app")`

Comment: @EstusFlask I'm not sure how to make methods from the root component **public**. `vm.someMethod()` does not work. I only see `vm._container`, `vm._component`, `vm._context` ...

Comment: See the previous comment. `vm` is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered by [Estus Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3731501/estus-flask) in the comments section.

**app.js**

```js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./app.vue";

let app = createApp(App)
let vm = app.mount("#app"); //This return instance is the proxy to the VueJs component

window.vm = vm;
```

Answer (score 3):

In Vue 3, to access the internal methods of a component, you should consider using `defineExpose` to expose the method in that component

https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose